How to improve responsiveness of interactive plotly generated line plots saved as html files?
I have some very long time series data (millions of data points) and generate interactive plotly html plots based on this data.  I am using Scattergl from plotly's graphical_obects.
When I attempt to zoom in on these plots, the browser (both chrome and firefox) will go unresponsive.
Subsampling the data obviously helps at the expense of resolution.
I know that there are packages that claim to handle this for example, but this is not an ideal approach for my use-case.
I am using an old macbook pro but when have observed the same phenomena on more modern, powerful machines.
Has anyone found a good solution for this problem?

You are reaching the limits of what you can do with plotly itself.
As you've already figured, WebGL handles large amounts of data better than the SVG renderer. The performance will start degrading around 1 million datapoints.
I am not sure what the bottleneck is from there, but would guess it is the JavaScript overhead or maxing out the memory the browser can allocate to a tab. But this is the general challenge when working with bigger data sets. You'll need some form of resampling or on-demand loading.
If you cannot subsample, you'll need to look into other frameworks since native plotly does not support on-demand loading by itself.
